# c++ opengl bmp and alpha channel

Tags: c++, opengl, bmp, alpha-transparency

I have some bmp's saved in 32bit via photoshop.
The first 24 bit should represent RGB and the last 8 bit should represent the alpha channel.
I'm loading my bitmap:

```
Bitmap* bStart = new Bitmap("starten.bmp");
```

I'm loading the file and setting the values for the alpha channel

```
Bitmap::Bitmap(const char* filename) {
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if(file != NULL) { // file opened
        BITMAPFILEHEADER h;
        fread(&h, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, file); //reading the FILEHEADER
        fread(&this->ih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, file);

        this->pixels = new GLbyte[this->ih.biHeight * this->ih.biWidth * this->ih.biBitCount / 8];
        fread(this->pixels, this->ih.biBitCount / 8 * this->ih.biHeight * this->ih.biWidth, 1, file);
        fclose(file);

        for (int i = 3; i < this->ih.biHeight * this->ih.biWidth * this->ih.biBitCount / 8; i+=4) {
            this->pixels[i] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the texture:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bStart->ih.biWidth, bStart->ih.biHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bStart->pixels);
```

the init stuff:

```
glutInit(argcp, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);

//not necessary because we using fullscreen
//glutInitWindowSize(550, 550);
//glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

glutCreateWindow(argv[0]); //creating the window
glutFullScreen(); //go into fullscreen mode

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); //art und weise wie texturen gespeicehrt werden

glClearColor (1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.0);

//setting the glut functions
glutDisplayFunc(displayCallback);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardCallback);

glutMainLoop(); //starting the opengl mainloop... and there we go
```

I can see my textures in my app but their background isn't transparent... it is kind of light blue.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> I have some bmp's saved in 32bit via photoshop. The first 24 bit should represent RGB and the last 8 bit should represent the alpha channel.

While this is possible to implement, this kind of alpha channel in a DIB file (that's what the structure of .BMPs is actually called) has never been properly specified. So it might simply be not stored at all. But that doesn't matter as you overwrite the alpha values with 1 in your DIB loader... I mean that part:

> ```
> for (int i = 3; i < this->ih.biHeight * this->ih.biWidth * this->ih.biBitCount / 8; i+=4) {
>         this->pixels[i] = 255;
>     }
> ```

Comment: yeah the 4th channel is declared as X and i red it should store some information about padding... that's why i overwrite the byte myself.

Comment: @skelle: so where do you think the alpha is stored then? also this contradicts the first sentence of your question.

Comment: @TomWhittock The alpha channel should be stored in the 4th channel which i overwrite with 255 for each pixel. Also i tell my texture to use RGBA but I don't get a transparent background

Comment: @skelle: 255 alpha == 0% transparency. I'm not sure what you are expecting by overwriting the alpha channel.

Comment: @TomWhittock Ahhhh ok I have to put in 0 and not 255 >_< my fault

Comment: @skelle: Um, ok? But you're still overwriting the alpha channel you exported from photoshop...

Comment: @TomWhittock: You're supposed to write there nothing at all. The alpha channel is supposed to come from your file. By writing that hardcoded value there, you're ignoring whatever transparency values Photoshop might have written into it (though I doubt it, because DIB doesn't specify alpha). For an easy to parse image file format that supports an alpha channel use TGA.

Comment: That was exactly my point. Photoshop does export alpha into that channel, however - it's a fairly common extension to the BMP format.

Comment: @TomWhittock: I know that it's a commonly used "extension". And actually I think it might have been me who either popularized it, or at least reinvented it once. About 10 years ago I published source code for some tool that allows you to take 2 DIB images (BGR + indexed/grayscale) and merge them into a BGRA DIB. This tool came with some code to load such bitmaps into OpenGL textures. So yes, I'm fully aware of that being possible, as I once came up with that scheme myself.

Comment: Ok, that's cool. It's very useful - it has helped me out quite a few times in the past. I was trying to clarify to the parenthesised doubt in your previous comment.